# Combine multiple SQL query results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working with PHP and I have made this code:
`

```
        $categories = array('casual','dinner', 'kids');
            $numberOfCategories = count($categories);

                for ($i=0; $i < $numberOfCategories; $i++) { 
                    
                    $req = $pdo->query('
                    SELECT ProductID
                         , ProductCategoryID 
                      FROM products 
                     WHERE ProductCategoryID LIKE "%'.$categories[$i].'%" 
                     ');
                    
                    while (${"relatedProduct" . $i} = $req->fetch()) {
                        var_dump(${"relatedProduct" . $i});
                    }
                }
```

`

After running the code I got the following result:
[image: Query Results]

If you look at it closely, you will notice that certain products repeat them self (which is normal).

What I want to do now his to combine the result of each loop stored in the variable `${"relatedProduct" . $i}` and filter that result(result after combining the result of each loop) to avoid repetition of products based on the column `ProductID`

Kindly help me solve this problem.

Comment: How/why is ProductCategoryID a comma separated list???

Comment: Any chance you may refactor your DB? Just create `ProductCategory (ProductId, Category)` table and let DBMS do the job with proper query,

Comment: A like '%something%' query in a loop? that's a database killer. As others have suggested before me you need to rethink your database design.

Comment: @Strawberry I was having an array that I was supposed to insert in `ProductCategoryID`, so I used the function `implode()` to separate the different elements of the array, so that they can be insert in the table

Comment: Yes. See normalization, and redesign your schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid inclusion of strings directly into SQL (potential danger of SQL injection attacks). Use parameterized prepared statements instead.

`DISTINCT` will give you unique rows (Prod.ID / Cat.ID combination). You can combine the search needles with `|` and compare it as a regular expression by `RLIKE`. The result is the sum of what you get with `LIKE %needle%` on each.

```
$req = $pdo->prepare('
  SELECT DISTINCT
    `ProductID`,
    `ProductCategoryID`
  FROM
    `products`
  WHERE
    `ProductCategoryID` RLIKE :pattern
  ');

$categories = array('casual','dinner', 'kids');
$cats = implode("|", $categories);

$req->bindParam(':pattern', $cats, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdo->query(' SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ProductCategoryID) as  ProductCategoryID
                      FROM products 
                     WHERE ProductCategoryID LIKE "%'.$categories[$i].'%" 
                     ');
```

using this U'll get a single row with all productCategoryIDs with matching conditions.

Now you can use array_unique() function to get unique ProductCategoryID